# ASP.net Product Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a website using ASP.net/C# and I'm a little unsure as to how to go about the products page. I want to display the items in a sort of grid view, I know that you can insert s grid view with a data source, but I'm not sure how to go about adding a "Add to Basket" button. I have a database with movies ID, title, description, imagepath etc.

Could I get some advice on this matter, it will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that with the help of linkButton in a ListView/Repeater

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAddToBasket" runat="server" CommandName="AddToBasket" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("moviesID") %>' CssClass="some_good_looking_css_for_botton">Add To Basket</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in code behind, handle ItemCommand for "AddToBasket" and with the help of "moviesID" then you can do the rest.

Comment: Ahh yeah just had a play about, seems simple enough and all I really have to do is pass the movieID using the add to basket, cheers matey.